# Difference in difference regression after propensity score matching

Tags: econometrics, difference-in-difference, matching, treatment-effect

I’m doing some matching followed by difference-in-difference regression to look at the impact of a certain disease on people's income. The matching is done, and I’m preparing to go into the next stage, setting up a difference in difference regression and achieving double robustness by including the same covariates I used during matching.

Currently, I matched individuals in the treatment and the controls based on the quarter that the treatment had their diagnosis. The covariates I included in the propensity score model include age, ethnicity, area of residence and previous health care utilization, etc. My variables for previous healthcare utilization include the number of GP visits in the previous year, the number of nights in the hospital in the previous year etc. The data structure is cross-sectional. So, I used this cross-sectional data to do the matching, and then have the IDs of the treatment and the matched controls. I now plan to grab additional information based on the IDs of the treatment and the matched controls to estimate the difference in difference regression. For the DND regression, I’m going to get monthly data for these matched IDs, and that turns my data into a panel data structure. (The outcome of interest is monthly income)

My question is, given that I matched the treatment and the controls using cross-sectional data, with variables like the number of GP visits in the previous year before the cancer diagnosis, how do I include this variable in the DND regression? In other words, when the matching was done, I included some variables that already have a built-in time dimension, how do I then include that in the DND regression to achieve double robustness? Do I still calculate how many GP visits they’ve had in the previous year by each month? Or do I include the number of GP visits in that specific month?

I guess what I'm trying to ask here is how important is it that I use the same variables during matching and DND regression. Do they have to be specified the same or can I use different measures for the same variable?

Thanks so much for your help.